# android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed

Tags: android, renderscript

I've started to work with renderscript and wonder why it doesn't work on api 16 with support mode. For example in project https://github.com/harism/android_reimage in code :

```
scriptInvert = new ScriptC_invert(rs);
```

I catch Exception :

> Caused by: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
>   at android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptC.(ScriptC.java:69)
>
> at io.github.harism.lib.reimage.ScriptC_invert.(ScriptC_invert.java:42)
>
> at io.github.harism.lib.reimage.ScriptC_invert.(ScriptC_invert.java:34)
>
> at io.github.harism.lib.reimage.ReImage.(ReImage.java:56)
>
> at io.github.harism.lib.reimage.ReImage.from(ReImage.java:45)

Does someone have any idea why can this happen?

Example of .rs code that failed (https://github.com/harism/android_reimage/blob/master/reimage/src/main/rs/invert.rs):

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(io.github.harism.lib.reimage)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

void invert(uchar4 *inout, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    inout->r = 0xFF - inout->r;
    inout->g = 0xFF - inout->g;
    inout->b = 0xFF - inout->b;
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the .rs source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's funny but I found a core of an issue... My .rs files was in library module. That caused an issue because internalCreate(rs, resources, resourceID) in ScriptC returned 0 (wasn't able to find raw .bc files).

Answer (score 0):

Rename the RS function to be `root` if you'd like it to be automatically picked up as the kernel for your script. Or, change it to be:

```
void __attribute__((kernel)) invert(uchar4 *inout, uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
```

You will likely also run into a problem since you are not specifying an explicit output allocation. With the second form, replace the `void` return value with `uchar4` and be sure to set an output allocation in your java code.

Comment: If they use the kernel attribute, they have to switch away from the pointer syntax (i.e. they need an explicit input and then need to return 0xFF - the relevant input channels. They would need a temporary variable to do that, but it would look cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen!  I'd forgotten about the switch from pointer syntax.  Devil is in the details, right?!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here might be proguard stripping the code. Can you try disabling proguard and/or updating it to not remove anything related to the RS support library (or your custom code)?

Comment: I'm testing in debug mode where proguard is disabled.

Comment: Can you add more lines from logcat? They might explain why the script failed to load. The Java exception itself doesn't seem to have much detail.